# DataGridView and MessageBox

Tags: c#, datagridview, messagebox

I have a problem with a MessageBox in DGV. So, when I click cell opening context menu, next I click in this menu and should show the MessageBox, but not showing up. Why?

This is my code:

```
private void DGV1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
    }

private void optionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure?", 
              "Are You Sure", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
       if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
         {
           ......
         }
     }
```

This MessageBox not showing up, but in application nothing can be done, as if the MessageBox was hidden.
I'm trying this:

```
MessageBox.Show(new Form { TopMost = true }, "Message");
```

But still not working :(

Comment: Maybe you need to set the MessageBox's parent?

Comment: put a breakpoint and see if it's hitting the event

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following below
This works so perhaps there is an issue in your contextmenu code and or DGV event can you provide more code.?

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure?", "Are You Sure", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //do something
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: Also ContextMenu's usually work off of Right Button Mouse Clicks so I am expecting to see some sort of KeyUp or KeyDown or KeyPress event handler as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply!

just now I trying this: ( DGV1.Visible = false)

```
private void optionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DGV1.Visible = false

     DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure?", "Are You Sure", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
           ......

    }
}
```

And it's works. Why MessageBox didn't show on top, but under DGV? Except data in my dgv, I use more of the painting. It is through this? Strange, because before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is frustrating problem. I had this same issue and Google was not a lot of help. Eventually I discovered that if you have implemented the CellFormatting event of the DataGridView (and perhaps other events that override the display logic) MessageBoxes will NOT be displayed over the DataGridView until the window is redrawn. To work around this behavior there are a few options, here are two.

1) Cheese method (hide and show Grid)

```
MyGrid.Visible = false;
MessageBox.Show("my message text");
MyGrid.Visible = true;
```

2) Better method (Detach event before Message, and reattach after)

```
MyGrid.CellFormatting -= MyGrid_CellFormatting;
MessageBox.Show("my message text");
MyGrid.CellFormatting += MyGrid_CellFormatting;
```

3) And wrap it up on your Form as a helper

```
private DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string p_text, string p_caption, MessageBoxButtons p_buttons, MessageBoxIcon p_icon) {
    bool detached = false;
    try {                
        // detach events
        MyGrid.CellFormatting -= MyGrid_CellFormatting;        
        detached = true;
        // show the message box
        return MessageBox.Show(p_text, p_caption, p_buttons, p_icon);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally {
        if(detached) {
            // reattach
            MyGrid.CellFormatting += MyGrid_CellFormatting;            
        }        
        MyGrid.Invalidate();        
    }         
}
```